# Spring GenericFilterBean @AutoWired hibernate property is null

Tags: spring, hibernate, autowired

A simple filter implementation:

```
public class SessionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("SessionFilter : doFilter called. Opening session...");
    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        System.out.println("Its null");
    }
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("SessionFilter : doFilter calling filter chain..");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    System.out.println("SessionFilter : doFilter closing session.");
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("SessionFilter : doFilter finished.");
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory =sessionFactory;
}
```

}

WEB.xml:

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>lt.maze.controller.SessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And a part of my application context xml file:

```
<beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="SessionFilter" class="lt.maze.controller.SessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

For some reason the variable sessionFactory is always null, I get a null point exception(and that print prints "its null"). The full message is 16-Aug-2015 23:51:38.383 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [maze] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException

EDIT:I added more prints to `SessionFilter`s `setSessionFactory` method:

```
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    System.out.println("SesionFilter : setSessionFactory called");
    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        System.out.println("SessionFilter : setSessionFactory. sessionFactory is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println("SessionFilter : setSessionFactory. sessionFactory isnt null");
    }
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    System.out.println("After assignment this.sessionFactory null? " + (this.sessionFactory == null));
}
```

Which print out

```
SesionFilter : setSessionFactory called
SessionFilter : setSessionFactory. sessionFactory isnt null
After assignment this.sessionFactory null? false
```

So how can sessionFactory be null afterwards if its value isn't changed?

Comment: are you sure that Spring scan package includes the filter package?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The filter is lt.maze.controller.SessionFilter and my package scan is set to lt.maze.

Answer (score 1):

Solved(I think) by changing the filter class in filter attribute:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make SessionFilter part of spring context.

@Component
public class SessionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

}

and instead of creating it object manually inject it dependency by using

@Autowired
private SessionFilter  sessionFilter;